# Split algorithm over two pages, inside a for loop

Tags: floats, page-breaking, algorithmic

I have found questions similar to mine, but none of the solutions given solves my problem.

Because my algorithm is too long to fit on one page, I want it to be split on two pages. Solutions I've found involve splitting the algoritm into two `algorithmic` environments, and add in the second something like:

```
\Continuedfloat
```

However, I use

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
```

and I need to keep the float environment, because I want to use a caption and other things. Perhaps there is a way of defining a caption in the `algorithmic` environment... is there? I haven't found one.

Another problem associated with splitting the algorithm in two is that I would need to define my for loop, which spans the whole algorithm, twice; I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}`
    `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
      `\usepackage{algorithm}`
       `\usepackage{algorithmic}`
     `\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My really important caption I need at this place}
\label{alg:entriesNonAl}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{\(j=e\) \TO \(s\)} %the main loop
\STATE ...
\STATE a lot of states coming
%....  somewhere in-between it gets to long, so i want the algorithm to be split on two pages
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}`
Sorry I know this is not the right formatting but I don't get how to add a code into a comment